# 特定のモデルに別モデルのカラムを別名で追加する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql

このような`SQL`を使い`Company`に `belongs_to`である `Balance`モデルと`Backwardation`モデルの同一日時のものをまとめて取得してるのですが、

```
sql =<<-SQL
 SELECT balances.*, backwardations.rate
 FROM balances LEFT JOIN backwardations
   ON balances.date = backwardations.date AND balances.company_id = backwardations.company_id
 WHERE balances.company_id = #{company_id}
SQL
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql).to_hash
```

できれば`Hash`ではなく`Balance`モデルに擬似的に`backwardation_rate`カラムを追加した状態で取得したいと思っています。
`AS`などを使ってそのようなことはできますか？

`Balance.select`文でどうにかならないかも考えましたが、自動的に`FROM "balances"`が最後に来てしまうため無理そうでした。

`Balance`も`Backwardation`も`company_id`と`date`カラムで`unique`制限をつけています。
DBは`Postgresql`を使用しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AS`を使い別名を付けて、`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all`ではなく`Model.find_by_sql`で取得すれば別モデルのカラムを別名で取得することができました。

```
sql =<<-SQL
 SELECT balances.*, backwardations.rate AS backwardations_rate
 FROM balances LEFT JOIN backwardations
   ON balances.date = backwardations.date AND balances.company_id = backwardations.company_id
 WHERE balances.company_id = #{company_id}
SQL
balance = Balance.find_by_sql(sql)

balance.backwardations_rate #=> 0.5
```